# How can I break out of a function

Tags: c

I need to check for certain condition. If that is true, certain operation will be performed and then need to break out of function. If condition not satisfied then proceeding normal operations in the function will continue.

Answer (score 8):

The `return`  keyword is used to exit from a function.

If the function has a non-`void` return type, an expression of the appropriate type must be used with `return` to provide the return value:

```
/* Returns 2 * abs(a), where abs(a) denotes the absolute value of a. */
int twice_positive(int a)
{
  if(a < 0)
    return -2 * a;
  return 2 * a;
}
```

Some people consider "early return" from long(er) functions to be evil stylistically and to be avoided; I don't agree but I thought I should mention it.

Comment: why do some people think that?

Comment: i am using a void function. In that case, can I just use return?

Comment: @Jocke: because from a design stand-point a function, as a math function, has one set of inputs and one set of outputs, and it's easier to control and map then by using a single point of exit. It also makes troubleshooting easier, especially if you aren't using a debugger and need to instrument your code with output statements. It's an arguable approach, and while it's less common nowadays it's not necessarily better or worse but might depend on what you have at hand for your project (and on the programmers' background, "veterans" being more accustomed to that single-return style).

Comment: @Sampi: yes. Just write `return;`.

Comment: @Jocke This is possibly also a misinterpretation of a coding standard to do with fortran, where originally you could effectively pass a function a possible list of labels to which to return. Single point of entry/single point of exit meant you could only enter a function in one place and it would only return to one place